# OpenCart show category images on homepage?

Tags: php, image, thumbnails, opencart

I'm using the most up to date version of open cart.

What I'm wanting to do is show the image from the store category page on every page page, as I'm wanting to implement it into the menu. You can see what I mean here: http://www.tomrawcliffe.com/portfolio/strings-r-us/

In the cetegory.tpl file I found:

```
<?php if ($thumb) { ?>
    <div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?    >" /></div>
<?php } ?>
```

But I've come to realise that it's not as easy as copy and pasting this into the header.tpl etc.

What do I do!?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, open up `/catalog/controller/common/header.php`

Find this code

```
            // Level 1
            $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'     => $category['name'],
                'children' => $children_data,
                'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );
```

change it to

```
            // Level 1
            $this->load->model('tool/image');
            $image = empty($category['image']) ? 'no_image.jpg' : $category['image'];
            $thumb = $this->model_tool_image->resize($image, 100, 100);

            $this->data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'     => $category['name'],
                'children' => $children_data,
                'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                'thumb'    => $thumb,
                'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );
```

Then in `/catalog/view/theme/[your-theme-name]/template/common/header.tpl` simply use `$category['thumb']` wherever you need it

note that I've set the width and height to 100px in the above code, and you should change it as appropriate

Comment: I tried to explain my best, but didn't quite get it. What I want is the category image to be displaid in the menu, along with the category name. And I just want the parent category images, not subcats. Is that any better?

Comment: Take a look at the above, that should answer what you need

Comment: You absolute legend! Thank you.

Comment: no problem. Please mark the answer using the tick next to the vote :)

Comment: Thank you so much man, i edited it for Opencart 3.x and i use.