# Making category image as thumb in menu, OpenCart 2.0.x

Tags: image, opencart2.x

I am having a hard time to make this possible. what i am about to do is that i want category images in my menu as thumbs in Opencart 2.0.x.

I have put 'thumb'    => $thumb, in catalog/controller/common/header.tpl

Like this:

```
        // Menu
    $this->load->model('catalog/category');

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $data['categories'] = array();

    $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        if ($category['top']) {
            // Level 2
            $children_data = array();

            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $filter_data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $children_data[] = array(
                    'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                );
            }

            // Level 1

        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $image = empty($category['image']) ? 'no_image.jpg' : $category['image'];
        $thumb = $this->model_tool_image->resize($image, 100, 100);

            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'name'     => $category['name'],
                'children' => $children_data,
                'thumb'    => $thumb,
                'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
            );
        }
    }
```

And i also put the $category['thumb'] in catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl

Like this:

```
                <?php if ($categories) { ?>
            <nav id="navigation">
                <div class="boxed bg-navigation">
                    <div class="container">
                        <ul data-breakpoint="800" class="flexnav with-js lg-screen clearfix">
                            <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
                            <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" ><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
                                <ul class="list-unstyled ul-col-<?php echo $category['column']; ?>">
                                    <?php foreach (array_chunk($category['children'], ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column'])) as $children) { ?>
                                    <?php if ($category['column'] == 1) { ?> 
                                    <?php foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                    <li class="li-inline">
                                        <div>
                                            <?php foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
                                            <?php $category['thumb']?>
                                            <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <?php } ?>
```

What am i doing wrong here? i found this solution on Stack Overflow [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679580/opencart-show-category-images-on-homepage)

But i can't seem to fix this properly, it's probably a simple thing that i can't really see. I have done this before with another framework in OpenCart 1.5.6.4. But that also didn't helped me alot hehe. If you want i can paste the other code to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `$category['thumb']` contains only image source so in template file

Replace `<?php $category['thumb']?>`

With `<img src="<?php echo $category['thumb']?>" alt="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>"/>`

In addition in controller you are setting thumb of parent category and in template printing on child category so it will print same parent image again and again.

the `no_image.jpg` is replaced as `no_image.png` in latest version.

Comment: I tried your answer but i get Notice: Undefined index: image or thumb if i change to what we have written. I have tried everything. And changed some stuff but nothing seems to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and got this working on Opencart 2.1.0.1
Here is the catalog/controller/common/header.php file:

```
(line 113)
// Level 2
            $children_data = array();

            $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);

            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $filter_data = array(
                    'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                    'filter_sub_category' => true
                );

                $this->load->model('tool/image');
                $image = empty($child['image']) ? 'no_image.png' : $child['image'];
                $thumb = $this->model_tool_image->resize($image, 100, 100);

                $children_data[] = array(
                    'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                    'thumb'    => $thumb,
                    'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                );
            }
```

And here is my catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl file:

```
(line 108)
<li><a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $child['thumb']?>" alt="<?php echo $child['name']; ?>"/><br /><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
```

Hope this helps.